# real number and p(N) Equinumerosity

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am not familiar with all rule but I read about infinite set and 
Cantor's diagonal. I want to prove there is one to one correspondence between power set of natural number and real number.  I search a lot but I don't find anything.  Is it possible to give me a reference or prove that for me here.
I'm sorry for bad English.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bijection between $P(\mathbb{N})$ And $(0, 1)$.  Consider the numbers represented in binary after the point sign. Then if your sub set of naturals contains $n$ you set the $n+1$ didgit to 1 and to 0 otherwise.  This gives a unique encoding of each subset in the reals and vise versa.

For example $\{1\}$ is mapped to $0.01$, $\{1,2\}$ is mapped to $0.011$ and $\{3\}$ gives $0.0001$.

Comment: can you explain more with example? for example I relate {1} to ... or relate {1, 2} to ... or relate {3} to .... can you explain for me for this?